# Set username for repository when using SVK?

Tags: svk

I want to mirror a Subversion repository to a local folder using

```
svk mirror
```

But how can I specifify the username that shall be used for logging in to the repository? I already tried http://user@domain.tld/trunk but that's not working. The SVK help on the mirror parameter also didn't give any hint. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem a few days ago, and today I have finally found an answer (workaround). You need to connect to repository of internet using, for example, `TortoiseSVN`, it will ask you for proper credentials and store them along with SSL certificate. After that you can try to set mirror using SVK - it will use previously stored credentials and SSL certificate information. For me it worked just fine!

**P.S.** To remove stored SSL certificates you may refer *[user]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server* folder (Windows 7)